# rx-java buffer is losing items

Tags: rx-java

I have a PublishSubject that I subscribe to twice.  The first subscriber just counts the # of items processed, and this value always matches what I send through the observer.  However, the other subscriber is using a buffer and I often (75%) don't receive all of the items that went through the observer.  Am I using the buffer wrong?  I am waiting for longer than the timespan after I stop sending to the observer to make sure all items are processed.

```
Integer downloads1 = 0;
Integer downloads2 = 0;
PublishSubject<Object> subject = PublishSubject.create();
// this subscriber count matches the expected
subject.subscribe(s -> {
  synchronized (downloads1) {
    downloads1 += 1;
  }
});
// this subscriber seems to miss items about 75% of the time
subject.buffer(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 10).subscribe(list -> {
  synchronized (downloads2) {
    downloads2 += list.size();
  }
});
```

Comment: Where is the source Observable? Since you are using `synchronized`, I guess that your source Observable may have some issue. You need to make sure your Observable sends the message in the same thread or be synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're encountering this bug: https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/issues/534

And btw, instead of subscribe, you should use `reduce(R initialValue, Func2<R,? super T,R> accumulator)` with an initial value of 0, then you don't need to do any synchronization yourself.